# How to fix Android Navigation Icon Size Problem

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I'm trying to create a custom toolbar. I changed the navigation icon using `setNavigationIcon`  but the svg vector I provided doesn't look right. Navigation icon does not automatically adjust the size of svg itself? How can I fix this problem?

Here is a example image left side menu icon not display correctly:
[image]

Here main_activity code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Toolbar
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_icon);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);


}
```

Custom toolbar code :

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    >

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: it shows like this because your icon size is large not enough to fit in the toolbar. Try to reduce the icon size or add custom height in your toolbar